# Write column values to file with matching value from second column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df` in R that has several columns, of which `columnA` and `columnB` are of interest here:

```
columnA    columnB
ab1        'This is a string'
ts4        'This is another string'
pq9        'This is yet another string'
```

I want to write the strings to a file and include the matching `columnA` value in the filename.

```
sapply(df$columnB, function(x){
  write.table(x,
          file = paste("matching_column_a_",
                       which(x == df$columnB, arr.ind = T),
                       ".txt",
                       sep = ""),
          col.names = FALSE,
          row.names = FALSE,
          append=F,
          sep = "\t",
          quote = FALSE)
})
```

However, my try gives only an index of the rows but that is not of use for me.

Is there a way to write it to a file where the matching filename of the file with the `columnB` string is something like `matching_column_a_ab1.txt`, `...a_ts4.txt`, etc?

Comment: Why don't you loop it by `columnA` i.e. `lapply(df1$columnA, ...`.  Are you writing each row as a different dataset?  Also, you could loop through the sequence of rows.

Comment: Each row will be a new file yes (I know this is not neat but I need it for file-wise follow-up text analysis in python).

Comment: In that case, loop through the sequence of rows, `lapply(seq(nrow(df1)), function(i), ...)`

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to submit this as answer for others who might have a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the sequence of rows, use that index to subset the column values for writing it to different files.

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i)
       write.table(df1$columnB,
                  file = paste0("matching_column_a_", df1$columnA[i], ".txt"),
                  col.names = FALSE,
                  row.names = FALSE,
                  append=FALSE,
                  sep = "\t",
                  quote = FALSE) )
```